# Этимология слова сплетня

Tags: этимология

Добрый день подскажите этимологию слова "сплетня".

Answer (score 2):

Слово происходит от гл. сплести, от с- + плести. М.Фасмер. Но есть и другая версия. По мнению А. Н. Погребной-Александрова, слово сплетня происходит от плетень (забор из веток и прутьев вокруг сельского дома и его приусадебного хозяйства). Подробнее здесь:[Сплетня](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=747.hFhPGdEqeQFYArtHLulMK1JtvmGV4_MyLFuqeEbbQhAP16c1xqlQ47QXabJ-zo6JnA-BNIEjeoJvIfuBAsnCUtfdAfmnOSnEKorJKO0s8aY.ebd52c6dc2356f335dbf8701118da03c93fedbf4&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9WCnKp0DidhEevVpSOOSPs_lvc7KhvxO9Rd9-WkgUqUJPE3DTbP1Y2ofLrWr-rGFqg&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxdmpPY0s3OElzNnNETFp4bVctdS1qc2ZHdEhnLW51eURFZFhfMldGNEhmZGNVVmZGc0pTanoxWTk0NzNOS1Z4Yk5ncE0tYzhzdmlrOEI2dHdZYzZyWXMyamVncl9IZms5ZzY1STkwdUwxVG9VMlhlOElLdzBPWTdtellFajdnemNWVl93Xzg3WXRYbQ&b64e=2&sign=3bd46205f8e6774a4e0a71dba5f537cc&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ5Hyx_fyvalFPA9KI5rmKu0WS7bRgCElMxpwHW8czAf5ulH3IZ7RVvKagk20DC41_RFue7BXJqhWvAn-BXO2xMEMTsZBJo5B9Gw41WLiX4u1fILp-VseggmBE0mxv908HIgrkBtIvZwNcwOrsXNXDgYHZ8tlDJkWu3-NC2KP8geRuIlwsLkTru-&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHpMQ80108_UCTdwuV_bvPyfSQ3Wu39WHEQuhu8kJcY3-lVZ6cAhlGndd28w5fjQg21dtBN0fOi2XUti_knFjYocIkd55jjT6Ccl3lwZ7KHH1tIR0KKq3xnaqWIYNAVFoNu9mqKbE3nJ4hqPKmwweOQwpP7D5qZQeR0Gjss6J_kUWUzhw-GOnt2WH8imw_MYSn9XB16PrgRjXaR9ZefvcyOpvW2jbR_7EF-upjJGJOmdEU4tL_aSJY9YoEgwFwLszL1qx2YlUz3L1mXJey5qXkzHpLw0h81a2ywbrv1WA2eG9fRWI-AJ611wHI_bj6zWnBqvq0W_r2gc7MyRBo_x9wYkrjV8MFoA9Y9Ij_w3OCF7QRx3rTG9MLi3_NPNXdgdRIcGLOtZhkU6NG8Oj_xKv9UQhMiHrb8UpWqsX0n4OgVu_XPtpXkDPzF3IzaY8RAgK40LoQOPdMvvKVVpLBeCpP5ULlGyECOx22rGVIhs_iyNAqlfp-mz8mIeeTZ4ynWFDSw&l10n=ru&cts=1436682870319&mc=4.919536294312568)

Comment: Ого! "Погребного-Александрова" уже стали цитировать?!

Comment: А что вас не устраивает?

Answer (score 0):

С-плетеня (с забора) - разговоры деревенские.

Update для бегемотуса:

"Сплетни деревенские" - общеупотребительное.

"Сплетения" - в деревне, наверняка, не использовалось.

"Сплетни", как и плетень из веток, суть всего и всех разговоров.

Корень - "тень в пле-тени". Дополнительная смысловая нагрузка - это неофициальный взгляд, "из тени".

Comment: а аргументировать?